# setBackgroundImage behaviour changed on ipad 4.2

Tags: ipad, uibutton, uiimage, ios-4.2

after the update to 4.2 the setBackgroundImage behaviour changed!
in my custom uibutton i have a white image as background (set with setBackgroundImage:forState:) and another image with a transparent layer (set with setImage:forState:)
On iPad 3.2 and on all versions of iPhone this gets rendered as

[image]

while on an iPad with ios 4.2 it gets rendered as

http://i52.tinypic.com/530005.png

i don't know whether the background image is spreading outside its bounds (256x128) or it reduces the size of the above image.
This happens both on device and on simulator.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: yes，i have the same problem,it could not fit the button if the button.size don't matches the image size

Answer (score 0):

Well after a long search, I couldn't find any *reason* behind this.

I worked around it by loading the custom button programmatically instead of from Interface Builder.

I hope it helps.